# CXF NoSuchMethodError ClassHelper.getRealClass

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf, cxfrs, cxf-client

Simple project, below is my gradle dependency. This is the only CXF dependency that I declare. Also are my gradle dependencies that materialize as the result of that declared dependency. When I run my code I get the exception below. I cannot figure this out.

Help!

```
compile(group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs', version:'2.7.17')

+--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:2.7.17
|    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:2.7.17
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:4.4.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:2.1.0 -> 2.2.1
|    |    +--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:1.7.1
|    |    \--- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.3
|    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:2.7.17
|    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:2.7.17 (*)
|    |    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.1.13 -> 2.2.11
|    |    \--- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:2.1.0 -> 2.2.1
|    +--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0-m10
|    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:2.7.17
|    |    \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:2.7.17 (*)
|    \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:2.7.17
|         +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:2.7.17 (*)
|         \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:2.7.17 (*)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.util.ClassHelper.getRealClass(Lorg/apache/cxf/Bus;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Class;
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory.setCommonProviders(ProviderFactory.java:499)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProviderFactory.setProviders(ClientProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory.initBaseFactory(ProviderFactory.java:137)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProviderFactory.initBaseFactory(ClientProviderFactory.java:77)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProviderFactory.createInstance(ClientProviderFactory.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.initClient(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:377)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.createWebClient(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:225)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.create(WebClient.java:113)
```

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError is generally when you use the new API jar but the implementation is still the old one which doesn't have the new methods implemented. I would suggest you to check the version of the jars and see if that is accurate. If you fix the version then you would not see this error.

Comment: Not following, the cxf-api version matches everything else, 2.7.17

Comment: You need to check for the implementation version not just API version.

Comment: Sorry not super familiar with what Jar I should be looking for that would contain the actual impl for this.

Comment: Im not sure what API you are using check http://cxf.apache.org/docs/27-migration-guide.html and see if it helps you.

Comment: Yeah I'm lost unfortunately. I am just using this WebClient class, within Spring-boot, w/ Tomcat 7 embedded. Not running a REST server or anything. On Java 8.

Comment: If possible the update all org.apache jars to the latest version.

Comment: I think this is a wild goose chase, from the stack trace ClassHelper does not implement anything from the cxf-api, so this is some other issue see: https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/common/util/ClassHelper.java